# How to get objects from criteria query in List in order of ids provided

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I have a list of ids say `[3,80,5,1]`

and i have all the records in the database , say Person class objects.

Is there a way to get the Person objects in the same order of the ids provided.

I mean that the result should give me the values

```
Person(id : 3),
Person(id : 80),
Person(id : 5),
Person(id : 1),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Person.getAll(3, 80, 5, 1)
```

Here is how [`getAll()`](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/getAll.html) works. The result list will bear the same order as that of the id's in the list.

It also accepts a list as an argument, so:

```
Person.getAll([3, 80, 5, 1])
```

should be good, or in general:

```
List ids = [3, 80, 5, 1]
Person.getAll(*ids)
```

should do as well.